# real life usages of (x+abs(x))/2

Tags: absolute-value, big-list

I know for all $x<=0$ that $y=0$ and that for all $x>=0$ that $y=x$. I have been wondering if there are any real-life uses of this equation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function

Comment: Are you looking for real life uses of the *function*, or for real life examples where that *expression* is used instead of $\max\{x,0\}$ to compute it?

Comment: @peterwhy ah yes I forgot this existed. That article actually brings up an interesting use that a forgot to mention. In Macaulay notation this is often required when looking at forces applied on beams etc.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am looking for real life uses of that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way you have worded it I presume you mean:
$$y=\frac{x+|x|}{2}$$
is the same as:
$$y=0,\,x\le0$$
$$y=x,\,x>0$$
This is similar in ways to how the [heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) would be used, as there are certain situations where an effect is only required after a given time.

---

E.g. If I have a varying force applied modelled by $\sin(t)$ for $t\ge0$ and then at a certain point, $t_0$ an additional increasing force is applied, this could be modelled as:
$$F=\sin(t)+\frac{(t-t_0)+|t-t_0|}{2}$$

---

Thanks to @peterwhy's comments which highlighted another use situation which I forgot which is Macaulay notation. This often takes the form $\langle x\rangle$ and is used in mechanics when looking at forces applied along beams. There is a whole article about Macaulay's method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay%27s_method)